# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp

below is my JSP and controller classes while i am running my application in tomcat i am getting this exception.

```
<form:form action="userDetails" method="post" commandName="user">
  <form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label>
  <form:input path="firstName"/><br/>
  <form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label>
  <form:input path="lastName"/><br/>
  <form:label path="nickName">Nick Name</form:label>
  <form:input path="nickName"/><br/>
  <form:label path="emailAddress">Email Address</form:label>
  <form:input path="emailAddress"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="userDetails",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeDetailsPost(@ModelAttribute("user")User user,ModelMap map){
        map.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
        map.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
        map.put("nicName", user.getNickName());
        map.put("email", user.getEmailAddress());
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: You have not added the exception!! Moreover you are using "post" as the request method but have used "GET" in your controller

Comment: i have both get and post methods in controller and my exception is strait forward..

Comment: Can you post the controller, from where you are going to jsp page?

Comment: i have two method in controller class with get and post.my jsp is index.jsp so it will load directly

Comment: I don't know if you have already found your way out, but can you edit your controller on the OP? It's not reflecting what you're stating on these comments. I've been through a similar situation and maybe I can help you out if didn't find a  solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method to your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
public User getUserForm() {
    return new User();
}
```

You have to make it available for the request. By this method spring will have initialized `User` object in the model and will be able to assign the values on the form submit request.

Comment: what is the different here taking the @modelattribute as parameter and as method level because i already used as  a parameter.

Comment: i added this method but no luck . can you pease tell me what it will do to prevent this exception

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userFormRender(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "jspPageName";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userFormAction(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("User firstName: " + user.getFirstName());

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

JSP:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="user">
  <form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label>
  <form:input path="firstName"/><br/>
  <form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label>
  <form:input path="lastName"/><br/>
  <form:label path="nickName">Nick Name</form:label>
  <form:input path="nickName"/><br/>
  <form:label path="emailAddress">Email Address</form:label>
  <form:input path="emailAddress"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form:form>
```